# Wordpress menu and WooCommerce categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to add all categories/subcategories links automatically to WP menu from WooCommerce plugin? 
I have many categories (20) and even more subcategories (100+) and I need them to be shown in the main menu at the top, in a hierarchical way.
I have tried from "Appearance->Menu" section to select all the categories at once in the menu, but they were all messed up, no hierarchy at all.
Is there a solution to avoid inserting all the categories/subcategories manually as menu items?

Comment: May I know why did I get a down vote? If the answer is so easy, can someone write it here please?

Answer (score 0):

please check this plugin

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/jc-submenu/screenshots/
```

with the help you just need to only one time to add menu like showing into the screenshot

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's not working, I see that I need to override custom walker of the theme, but I can't do it, I have modified it in my child theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a shortcode in menu item title and then use some hooks to replace that item based on that shortcode with taxonomy terms hierarchy, but it's a little bit more complicated code...

There are no free plugins that can do that...

BUT there are some paid plugins and the best one that offers most options and it is life-time-deal, so you pay just once is **Bulk Menu Creator PRO** - google it if you want ;)